# SQL Dependency on change event firing based on number of Connections

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sqldependency

I have just tried implementing sql dependency to detect changes in table, as far as implementation I am getting the trigger as soon as I change data in table, but problem is I am getting trigger based on number of connections. 
For example if I have my url open in 2 browsers then dependency on change event is triggered twice when there is a change in table, if it is opened thrice then three times my on change event is triggered and soon.

Here is the code that I tried.

```
        private void GetUsers()
        {   
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM dbo.[Users]";

                    command.Notification = null;

                    //  creates a new dependency for the SqlCommand
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    //  creates an event handler for the notification of data
                    //      changes in the database.
                    //  NOTE: the following code uses the normal .Net capitalization methods, though
                    //      the forum software seems to change it to lowercase letters
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(Dependency_OnChange);

                    connection.Open();

                    List<UserInfo> userList = new List<UserInfo>();
                    using (IDataReader userDataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (userDataReader != null)
                        {
                            while (userDataReader.Read())
                            {
                                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
                                userInfo.FirstName = Convert.IsDBNull(userDataReader["FirstName"]) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(userDataReader["FirstName"]);
                                userInfo.LastName = Convert.IsDBNull(userDataReader["LastName"]) ? string.Empty : Convert.ToString(userDataReader["LastName"]);
                                userList.Add(userInfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (userList != null && userList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        this.dgUserList.DataSource = userList;
                        this.dgUserList.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void Dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.GetUsers();

            // this will remove the event handler since the dependency is only for a single notification
            SqlDependency dependency = sender as SqlDependency;

            //  NOTE: the following code uses the normal .Net capitalization methods, though
            //      the forum software seems to change it to lowercase letters
            dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(Dependency_OnChange);


            // To broadcast my message
            ChatHub chat = new ChatHub();
            chat.send("myname", "New Registration Done");
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the behavior you expect to see?  It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I need dependency change event should be fired only once, everytime I change data in table

Comment: FYI, number of times dependency change event trigger increases by refresh of the page. for example if I refresh page twice then event fires twice and so on...

Comment: Are you calling the GetUsers method each time the page loads?  If so, this is registering a notification with the database each time you call that method.  If you only want to be notified once, you'll need to make a note that the notification was already registered and react accordingly.

Comment: but this is my page load
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                this.GetUsers();
            }
        }

Comment: you are the man, @Michael I guess that is the problem

Comment: Sure... so each time the Page_Load event is fired and there is no PostBack occurring, you register a NEW notification with the database.  Then, when the data changes, all of the notifications that are applicable are fired.

Comment: Perfect!!! bravo you saved my day. Thanks, but is refresh is not a postback? why I am getting IsPostBack as false on refresh?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50970/discussion-between-michael-bowersox-and-raghurocks)

Comment: did you solve it? if not I will post an answer.