# SqlDependency onchange fires multiple times for each browser instance

Tags: c#, sqldependency

Apologize for duplicate question. I have googled and everywhere I found only the question   but no successful solution. I am facing exactly the same issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154182/sql-dependency-on-change-event-firing-based-on-number-of-connections) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39006481/signalr-with-sqldepdency-firing-multiple-times-for-each-browser-instance) and struggling from past week,but I did not find any success, so finally I decided to ask a question here. I have tried to solve it myself by following the comments suggested in these question, but to success. I want SqlDependency onchange event to fire exactly once for any number for instance or users logged in.

This method is called once whenever a new user login into the application

```
 public List<TransactionMaster> GetUnregisteredTransactions()
    {
        List<TransactionMaster> ltrans = new List<TransactionMaster>();
        TransactionMaster trans = new TransactionMaster();

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT TransId,  ReceivedFrom,ReceivedOn,Mask FROM [dbo].TransactionMaster  WHERE StageId =1";
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                cmd.Notification = null;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                ltrans = dal.ConvertDataTable<TransactionMaster>(dt);
            }
        }
        return ltrans;
    }
```

And then again this method is called from onchange event

```
 private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            TransactionHub.GetUnregTransactions(GetUnregisteredTransactions());

    }
```

Comment: Although it is a duplicate; can you post the relevant information here?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question.

Comment: Please suggest a way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case each time event fired I added events to the dependency

```
 dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(SqlNotification.dependency_OnChange);
```

after I found [this solution](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1013100/SqlDependency-OnChange-Event-Fires-many-times-for), i changed my code to :

```
 dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(SqlNotification.dependency_OnChange);
 dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(SqlNotification.dependency_OnChange);
```

and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `GetUnregisteredTransactions` you are calling `dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);`, This is causing a new event to registered, so now you have two events that will fire. when the two events fire it will call `dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);` two more times making it 4 events that will fire. This number will double with every call till the object `dependency` is pointing at is garbage collected.

You need to either not re-register the dependency on calls from the event version (for example pass a `bool` to the function to know if it should do the registration or not) or you need to unregister the old notification before you create a new one.

Here is a example of unregistering.

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
    dependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        TransactionHub.GetUnregTransactions(GetUnregisteredTransactions());

}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried exactly the same, but no result. I understood this behavior - For eg when a user (A) login to the application, GetUnregisteredTransactions is executed and dependency is registered for this user. When some other user (B) login GetUnregisteredTransactions is again executed & a new dependency is registered for this user (B). Now if there is any change in table, onchange is executed 2 time since it is registered for 2 separate users. However onchange is de-registered & re-registered again 2 times.

Comment: So now the point is how can we make sure that GetUnregisteredTransactions is executed only once and dependency is registered only once. Can we do something to prevent duplicate registration once it is already registered irrespective of new login and browser instance.

Comment: please check my comments

Comment: You need to change `query` to have in the where clause a filter based on the ID of the user.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but I wanted to share my very fun experience with the SqlDependecy firing OnChange event multiple times.

So I ran into this problem as some people did and started looking for answers and quickly realized that there were no code examples that painted the whole picture of how to go about this problem.

This DatabaseWatcher class that I have snatched from
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency), I had to modify it to prevent multiple subscriptions to OnChange events that in the end cause multiple OnChange events to be fired due to what I suspect, multiple instances of SqlDepency floating around with those OnChange subscriptions still attached.

The way I go about is by applying the solution from Scott Chamberlain and then catching the current instance of the SqlDepency when subscribing to the OnChange event to make sure to unsubscribe from the OnChange event before liquidating the DatabaseWatcher instance.

Unrelated to the subject, I also forward the OnChange event to hide it in my business class.

```
public class DatabaseWatcher : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Forwards the original OnChangeEventHandler event with the database table notification data
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<SqlNotificationEventArgs> OnTableChange;
        public SqlDependency CurrentSqlDependencyInstance { get; set; }
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        public string Query { get; set; }

        public DatabaseWatcher(string connectionString, string query)
        {
            ConnectionString = connectionString;
            Query = query;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the database notification listener. Needs to be started before subscribing to the database notifications.
        /// </summary>
        public void StartDatabaseNotificationsListener()
        {
            // Create a dependency connection.
            SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionString);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Subscribes to the database table change notifications. After each notification, a new re-subscription is needed to receive the next database/table notification.
        /// </summary>
        public void SubscribeToDatabaseNotifications()
        {
            //create database connection
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                //open database conneciton
                connection.Open();

                // Create a new SqlCommand object.
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Query, connection))
                {
                    // Create a dependency and associate it with the SqlCommand.
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);

                    //catch current SqlDependency instance
                    CurrentSqlDependencyInstance = dependency;

                    // Subscribe to databas/table notifications
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

                    // Execute the command for the initial table snapshot to later compare with when changes arise
                    var affectedRowsCount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnDependencyChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            var sqlDependency = (SqlDependency)sender;

            //don't unsubscribe after the subscription event
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Subscribe)
                return;

            //unsubscribe from the OnChange event from the current instance of the SqlDepency object
            sqlDependency.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

            //don't fire the event if no changes were done to the table records
            if (e.Type != SqlNotificationType.Change)
                return;

            if (e.Info != SqlNotificationInfo.Insert && e.Info != SqlNotificationInfo.Delete)
                return;

            OnTableChange = new EventHandler<SqlNotificationEventArgs>(OnTableChange);
            OnTableChange?.Invoke(sender, e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops listening to database notifications, method is called on Dispose
        /// </summary>
        public void StopDatabaseNotificationsListener()
        {
            //unsubscribe from the OnChange event from the current instance of the SqlDepency object
            CurrentSqlDependencyInstance.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);

            SqlDependency.Stop(ConnectionString);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            StopDatabaseNotificationsListener();
        }
    }
```

So there it is, please leave comments, thoughts, etc,

Cheers.